# Converting a two-mode edge list to a one-mode edge list in R

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
Person  Team
  10    100
  11    100
  12    100
  10    200
  11    200
  14    200
  15    200
```

I want to infer who knew one another, based on what teams they were on together.  In other words, I want to create a data set that looks like this:

```
Person1 Person2 Count
  10      11      2
  10      12      1
  11      12      1
  10      14      1
  10      15      1
  11      14      1
  11      15      1
```

The resulting data set captures the dyadic relationships that can be inferred based on the teams that were outlined in the original data set.  The "Count" variable reflects the number of instances that a dyad was on a team together.  Also, it doesn't matter which ID is listed as Person1 versus Person2, since the relationships are undirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

```
do.call(rbind,tapply(dat$Person,dat$Team,function(x)t(combn(x,2))))

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   10   11
# [2,]   10   12
# [3,]   11   12
# [4,]   11   13
# [5,]   11   14
# [6,]   11   15
# [7,]   13   14
# [8,]   13   15
# [9,]   14   15
```

#### edit after Op edit :

personaly I would use a specified package like `igraph package` to do this but here you can do it in 2 steps.

```
res <- 
setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame,
        tapply(dat$Person,dat$Team,
               function(x)t(combn(x,2)))),
        c('Person1','Person2'))
## compute frequencies of each pair and add it to unique version of res
cbind(unique(res),
      Count=as.vector(table(paste(res[,'Person1'],res[,'Person2']))))

#         Person1 Person2 Count
# 100.1      10      11     2
# 100.2      10      12     1
# 100.3      11      12     1
# 200.2      10      14     1
# 200.3      10      15     1
# 200.4      11      14     1
# 200.5      11      15     1
# 200.6      14      15     1
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!  I actually edited my request slightly, but I want to acknowledge that your code does fulfill my original request! :)